# How to read Kafka Topic from beginning with Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, apache-kafka

https://github.com/ekimcoskun/KafkaMessageApp/tree/main/tata/src/main/java/com/example/tata/comp

I am trying to read kafka topic from beginning and list on Frontend (React)

Answer (score 0):

If you configure `auto.offset.reset=earliest` property on your consumer factory, then the consumer group will start from the latest offset upon startup. If there is an offset commit, though, the app will start from the committed offset

See all properties here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

If you want to render a UI for data, you may want to look at using the InteractiveQueryService class